# Multithreading, can't make another thread working

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I'm trying to create a thread for every request that is comming in. This is a short example from what i'm making. The problem is that i can write the first incomming request to a list but when i try to send the second request it stops working when it need to send a signal to my function "request_loop".

So it works perfect till there. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? The program don't want to work further than this.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "tcpsocket.h" 
#include <sys/select.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 

#define NUM_HANDLER_THREADS 3 /* number of threads used to service requests */
pthread_mutex_t request_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t got_request = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZE]; 
unsigned char collect_buffers[2000];

struct timespec timeout; 
struct timeval tv;

int num_requests = 0;
int num; 
int rc = 0;
struct request {
    int number;
    struct request* next;
};
struct request* requests = NULL;
struct request* last_request = NULL;
```

This is the function where i add a request. When i want to write the second thread to my list it stops working...

```
void add_request(int request_num,pthread_mutex_t* p_mutex,pthread_cond_t* p_cond_var)
{
    int rc;
    struct request* a_request;
    a_request = (struct request*)malloc(sizeof(struct request));
    if (!a_request) { /* malloc failed?? */
        fprintf(stderr, "add_request: out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    a_request->number = request_num;
    a_request->next = NULL;

    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(p_mutex);

    printf("NUMBER OF REQUESTS: %d\n",num_requests);
    if (num_requests == 0) { /* special case - list is empty */
        printf("list is empty\n");
        requests = a_request;
        last_request = a_request;
        printf("REQUEST NUMBER:%d",a_request->number);
    }else{
        printf("created list\n");
        last_request->next = a_request;
        last_request = a_request;
    }

    num_requests++;
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(p_mutex);
    printf("send signal");
    rc = pthread_cond_signal(p_cond_var);
    printf("signal sended");
}
```

This is the function where i want to write my data to my list. After that i remove the request with : free(request);

```
struct request* get_request(pthread_mutex_t* p_mutex){
    printf("NUMBER REQUESTS (get request): %d\n",num_requests);    
    int rc;
    struct request* a_request;

    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(p_mutex);
    if (num_requests > 0) {
        a_request = requests;
        requests = a_request->next;
        printf("REQUEST NUMBER:%d\n",a_request->number);
        if (requests == NULL) { /* this was the last request on the list */
            last_request = NULL;
            printf("last request is NULL\n\n");
        }
        num_requests--; //remove REQUEST
    }else { /* requests list is empty */
        printf("list is empty\n");
        a_request = NULL;
    }
    //remove request
    free(a_request);

    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(p_mutex);
    /* return the request to the caller. */
return a_request;
}
```

This is the loop where i handle the requests till there are no requests anymore

```
void* handle_requests_loop(void* data){
    //rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&request_mutex);    
    printf("NUMBER REQUESTS (loop): %d\n",num_requests);
    int rc;
    struct request* a_request;
    int thread_id = *((int*)data);

    while(num_requests > 0){

        printf("THREAD ID : %d\n",thread_id);
        a_request = get_request(&request_mutex);

        if(num_requests == 0){
            printf("NO REQUESTS\n\n");
        }else{
            printf("THERE ARE REQUESTS\n\n");
        }

    }
    while(num_requests == 0){
        printf("wait");
        rc = pthread_cond_wait(&got_request, &request_mutex);

    }
}
```

I wrote a test function for this that generates 2 threads. The first one works fine, the other one stops working when he need to send a new signal to the thread loop.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ 
    printf("StartUp\n"); 

    //---------------------------Create Threads--------------------------------
    for (i=0; i<NUM_HANDLER_THREADS; i++) {
        thr_id[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&p_threads[i], NULL, handle_requests_loop,(void*)&thr_id[i]);
    }

    //--------------------------INTERRUPT--------------------------------------
    int j;
    for(j=1;j<3;j++){
    printf("ADD REQUEST\n");
    add_request(j, &request_mutex, &got_request);

    delay.tv_sec = 5;
    delay.tv_nsec = 10;
    nanosleep(&delay,NULL);

    } 
      return 0; 
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Many thanks!!

Comment: This is probably *way* too much code for anyone to feel excited about. Try narrowing your problem down, and make sure you actually understand all the ingredients very well on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what your specific problem is.  I would need you to be much more specific about what happens when you only have one receiver thread, and to run in a debugger and tell us what line of code each of your threads get stuck at.  It is not clear from your write-up, for example, whether it is the main thread or one of the child threads that is getting "stuck".  It's also not clear whether you observe the stuckness when you only create a single child thread (let alone two child threads) rather than three.

That said there is one bug, and a couple of things that you could clean up that would make it easier on yourself when you are trying to figure these things out on your own.

The bug is that at the bottom of `handle_requests_loop()` you are calling `pthread_cond_wait()` with `&request_mutex` *even though you don't currently have `request_mutex` locked*.  This results in undefined behavior (which might include permanently disabling either or both the threads calling `pthread_cond_wait()` *or* `pthread_cond_signal()`).

Among the things you could clean up:

1. You are initializing your mutex with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.  This creates *non-recursive* mutexes.  If the same thread tries to lock the mutex twice it will deadlock with itself.  You should either initialize with an attribute of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` or be extremely careful not to double-lock.  For example: if you uncomment the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call on the first line of `handle_requests_loop()` you are *guaranteed to deadlock yourself*  when you call `pthread_mutex_lock()` at line 5 of `get_request()`.
2. You create some threads in `main()` but do not call `pthread_join()`.  This is probably fine for now, but some time in the future you might unthinkingly call `pthread_create()` with a reference to some data on main()'s stack, and *that* would result in a serious problem (of undefined behavior.)
3. You are leaving `handle_requests_loop()` with neither a `return` statement nor calling `pthread_exit()`.  You need one or the other (at least return NULL).
4. I cant' figure out what you are doing with `requests` vs `last_request` instead of just having one variable.  (It looks wrong, but I can't figure it out, so it might, by pure luck, be okay.)
5. You are freeing `a_request` near the bottom of `get_request()` but then returning it to `handle_requests_loop`.  That can only lead to sadness and hurt feelings in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for you replay! I will look this. Thinks this will help me little bit further! THANKS

Comment: I tried some stuff with pthread join(). So when a request is comming in a execute the function pthread_join(thread1,NULL). But how can i use that thread again in the next loop? I tried some stuff like pthread_exit(NULL) in my thread function but it closes the entire program. Do you know a solution for this? Hope you understand my question